# Change the language in the application completely

Tags: java, android

faced with such a problem that the language of the application does not change completely, if I change the language, then at first glance everything is fine, but if I open alertdialog The language will be the same as in the system, but not the one that was selected manually .

Comment: Did you use Locale?

Comment: Could you show us how you call the `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to get title string from strings.xml.

```
alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.abc));
```

Now create two different folders for different language and put same name of xml in both folder with different language.

For English language android will pick res/values/strings.xml folder:

```
<string name="abc">abc</string>
```

For polish language android will pick res/values-pl/strings.xml folder:

```
<string name="abc">ABC</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the `Context` of your application is completely updated. `Dialogs` use the application context, so that is the reason they are not displayed in the new language. This is the reason why most of the apps ask your for reopen the app.